# Min and Max with python functions

Tags: python, function, max, min

so i was trying to making it so from my function it could print the minimum and maximum number but I'm confused on where to go. My current code is:

```
def multiplyList(nums):
    for i in range (len(nums)):
        nums[i] = (nums[i]*5)
    return nums

print (multiplyList(([1,2,3,4,5])))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error ? What are u expecting ? Plz  elaborate

Comment: Hoping that it could print the minimum and maximum number

I'm either getting `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'`


Or

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your posted code makes no attempt to find minimum and maximum elements.  Also, Python has built-in functions `min` and `max`.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Hi there Prune and thanks for commenting, when i use min and max it comes up with this.

`
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
 
y`

Comment: You are returning the whole list so printing `multiplyList([1,2,3,4])` will print the list not the max/min

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is getting the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and/or [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). You'll need to call it on the `nums` list of integers:

```
min(nums)
```

or for maximum value:

```
max(nums)
```

Now if you want to `print` is as simple as calling `print(min(num))`
For completeness here is what I THINK you're asking for:

```
    def multiplyList(nums):
        for i in range (len(nums)):
            nums[i] = (nums[i]*5)
        return min(nums) # or max(nums)

print (multiplyList(([1,2,3,4,5])))
```